# Replace empty values in a SELECT statement using IIF()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this following query :

```
SELECT       YEAR(RequestDate)
             ,Keycode
             ,IIF(CustomerFullName=' ','Undefined',CustomerFullName) AS CustomerFullName
             ,COUNTRY
             ,RequestDate
             ,NextOrderDate
             ,Channel
             ,SalesRep
FROM Sales.Order
```

I want to replace the empty values of the CustomerFullName column with Undefined, I get this following error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Looks fine, but there is no line 37 in this code. Please show the *actual* code that throws the error

Comment: There is no problem in this code, Show complete code please

Comment: I updated the error message.

Comment: I think the OP version of SQL Server is 2008

Comment: @StrangePerson . . . Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?  All supported versions support `IIF()` (sadly).

Answer (score 0):

[IIF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a SQL Server 2012 feature.

```
 SELECT       YEAR(RequestDate)
                 ,Keycode
                 ,COALSCE(NULLIF(CustomerFullName, '','Undefined') AS CustomerFullName
                 ,COUNTRY
                 ,RequestDate
                 ,NextOrderDate
                 ,Channel
                 ,SalesRep
    FROM Sales.Order
```

Or you replace your IIF with a CASE ( Which is what SQL 2012 would do anyway ) :

```
SELECT CASE CustomerFullName WHEN '' THEN 'Undefined' ELSE CustomerFullName END
```

Comment: I would not call `IIF()` a "feature".  It is a function whose sole purpose appears to be backwards compatibility to MS Access -- given that `CASE` does the same thing and a lot more.  Compatibility to MS Access seems like a step backwards to me.  They should've put `CASE` in MS Access instead.